# Traverse to all the Views in a Custom Layout ListView

Tags: android

My ListView has 10 rows, each row has a `TextView` and a `Button`. Everytime I click on a `Button` I want to traverse to each `Button` in my row to check its drawable.
The challenge is, it returns all null except the View I clicked.
Anyone got an idea as to how I can achieve this? Check code snippet below.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

    TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    ListView listParent = (ListView) parent;

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            for(int ctr=0; ctr<listParent.getCount(); ctr++) {
                //traverse to all the buttons in list here
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you only set the onclick listener to just one button with id = button. so it's only to work for one button even if you call all buttons with the same name. I recomend to do identify every single button as button1 button2 button3...button10 you can use a for(){} and set the onclick listener of every single button too.

Comment: This is a code snippet of my Adapter for my custom ListView. By the time I set listview.setAdapter(myAdapter); it creates a listener to all my buttons automatically. Want I want is, if I click button1, i want to check button0, button2, button3, etc. to check their drawables.

Comment: did you try this to get the button? Button wantedbutton = listView.getChildAt(ctr); and what do you mean when you say to check its drawable?

Comment: If the button is setting up the preferred drawable based on my audio. So, my Audio playing implementation was set inside this adapter. Anyway, if nothing is going on, I might transfer this implementation to my Activity.